# Can we conduct conferencing in the backgroud using Twilio Video API?

Tags: twilio, video-conferencing, twilio-video

We are planning to use `Twilio Video API` for conducting conferencing between multiple participants. We have an application for WEB, Android and iOS and we need to integrate Twilio service to our application.

In Mobile SDKs i.e `Android and iOS` can we join the conferencing call first and then can we have an option in the meeting room to switch back to our main application without disconnecting the conference call. All the attendees connected to the conference will be able to hear and see the participant who navigated to the other screen i.e our main app screen. Is this possible that a participant can move back and forth between the video conferencing and the main application?

The use case is similar to `WhatsApp video call` where user can chat to people and still present in the video call. Tech stack for Mobile device application is `Flutter`. Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate the plugin hosted on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video). The API docs can be found [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/twilio_programmable_video/latest/twilio_programmable_video/twilio_programmable_video-library.html).

Regarding your switch like WhatApp, you need to look into the Picture-in-Picture mode (PiP). Which is also part of the development fase of this plugin. You can find the milestone [here](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/milestones/4) and the issues related to it [here](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/issues?milestone_title=Background%20modes%20and%20PiP).

For Web it will also be implemented in the [Flutter](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/-/milestones/5) solution.